# Removing applications from Google+ Manage Apps page

Tags: google-plus

I can't see any way to delete apps from the [G+ Manage Apps](https://plus.google.com/apps) page. I can disconnect there, or revoke access from the [Google OAuth authorized  apps page](https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens), but I can't see any option to remove it altogether.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disconnecting using the [Google+ Apps page](https://plus.google.com/apps) will let you remove all the activities associated with the app, and will revoke access to your information to the app in question. It should also delete it from the list.

**Update**

For the record, this link currently redirects to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions which does the same thing.

Comment: To clarify, the app listing will go away if and only if you also delete the app activities that the app created.

Comment: Thanks, it was the deleting activities part I missed.

Comment: To delete / disconnect, click the pencil icon and a sub-menu appears. (The pencil icon is NOT the same as the edit link. Took me a while to work that one out.)